# Stabilizing a fragile web application by proxy

Tags: proxy, black-box

I'm having an unstable dynamic web application which I want to stabilize by running in this settings:

1. Given a GET request to url `U` I will

   1. Look for `U` in the cache - if it's already there - fetch it from the cache
   2. If it's not, generate the cache from the web application.
2. Administrator will be able to access the web application directly. Whenever he will access a webpage - the generated web page will be used to update the cache.

This way, I know for sure that even if the web application is down, most of the pages will still be accessible. And it is easy for the administrator to update the cache (whenever he edits something there - it'll be updated automatically, since he'll usually access this page afterwards).

Is there a generic cache with similar behavior? Any better ideas for stabilizing existing web application without changing its source code?

Comment: You could probably use Fiddler's AutoResponder tab for this (www.fiddler2.com)

Comment: It doesn't look as if it fit to run in production though.